# error while sending email using IBM watson (Exception when evaluating action credentials: "$private.cf_creds" SpEL evaluation error:)

Tags: ibm-watson

I have created a chatbot to helpdesk ticket and want to to send an email to the service desk At the final step when the user type yes send an email I am getting error as

Exception when evaluating action credentials:

> $private.cf_creds" SpEL evaluation error: Expression [ $private.cf_creds ] converted to [ context['private'].cf_creds ] at position 0: EL1007E: Property or field 'cf_creds' cannot be found on null (and there is 1 more error in the log)

The snippet below is of the JSON editor

```
{ "output": { "generic": [] }, "actions": [ { "name": "mahesh.patil@pansoft-tech.com_dev/examples/send_email", "type": "server", "parameters": { "email": "$destination_email", "application": "$application", "Error_Msg": "$Error_Msg" }, "credentials": "$private.cf_creds", "result_variable": "context.cf_response" } ] }
```

Comment: {
  "output": {
    "generic": []
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "mahesh.patil@pansoft-tech.com_dev/examples/send_email",
      "type": "server",
      "parameters": {
        "email": "$destination_email",
        "application": "$application",
        "Error_Msg": "$Error_Msg"
      },
      "credentials": "$private.cf_creds",
      "result_variable": "context.cf_response"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

seems like your initial configuration node (the node where you safe the API-key as well as the name of the cloud function and the destination mail as context) is not connected to your first appearing node (probably the welcome node). Make sure you set a "Jump to Initial Configuration (Evaluate response)" from the Welcome node to your initial configuration node to trigger the cloud function.